# DataFrame to Dictionary with different numbers of values Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to create a dictionary from a DataFrame where the key sometimes has multiple values.

For example:

```
df
ID     value 
A       10 
B       45
C       20
C       30
D       20
E       10
E       70
E       110
F       20
```

And I want the dictionary to look like:

```
dic = {'A': 10, 
       'B': 45, 
       'C':[20,30],
       'D': 20,
       'E': [10,70,110],
       'F': 20}
```

I tried using the following code:

```
dic=df.set_index('ID').T.to_dict('list')
```

But it returned a dictionary with only one value per ID:

```
{'A': 10, 
 'B': 45, 
 'C': 30,
 'D': 20,
 'E': 110,
 'F': 20}
```

I'm assuming the right way to go about it is with some kind of loop appending to an empty dictionary but I'm not sure what the proper syntax would be.

My actual DataFrame is much longer than this, so what would I use to convert the DataFrame to the dictionary?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

example dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'ID':['A', 'B', 'B'], 'value': [1,2,3]})


df_tmp = df.groupby('ID')['value'].apply(list).reset_index()


dict(zip(df_tmp['ID'], df_tmp['value']))
```

outputs

```
{'A': [1], 'B': [2, 3]}
```